# Adding new T to empty List<T> using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm attempting to set add a new instance of an Officer class to a potentially empty list using reflection.

These are my classes

```
public class Report(){
    public virtual ICollection<Officer> Officer { get; set; }
}

public class Officer(){
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Simplified code snippet:

```
Report report = new Report()

PropertyInfo propertyInfo = report.GetType().GetProperty("Officer");
object entity = propertyInfo.GetValue(report, null);
if (entity == null)
{
    //Gets the inner type of the list - the Officer class
    Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var listType = typeof(List<>);
    var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(type);
    entity = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
}
//The entity is now List<Officer> and is either just created or contains a list of
//Officers
//I want to check how many officers are in the list and if there are none, insert one
//Pseudo code:
if (entity.count = 0)
{
    entity.add(new instance of type)
}
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // "type" is the same variable you got a few lines above
((IList)entity).add(o);
```

Comment: entity is an object, it doesn't have an add method though - how do I cast it as List<type>?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Using dynamic:

```
dynamic list = entity;
if (list.Count = 0)
{
    list.Add(new instance of type)
}
```

2) Using Reflection:

```
var countProp = entity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).First(p => p.Name == "Count");
var count = (int)countProp.GetValue(entity,null);

if(count == 0)
{
   var method = entity.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).First(m => m.Name == "Add");
   method.Invoke(entity,new instance of type);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you asked for but may accomplish the same task.

```
public static ICollection<T> EnsureListExistsAndHasAtLeastOneItem(ICollection<T> source)
    where T : Officer, new()
{
    var list = source ?? new List<T>();
    if( list.Count == 0 ) list.Add(new T());
    return list;
}
```

If `Officer` doesn't have a default constructor then you could add a factory callback

```
public static ICollection<T> EnsureListExistsAndHasAtLeastOneItem
   (ICollection<T> source, Func<T> builder)
    where T : Officer
{
    var list = source ?? new List<T>();
    if( list.Count == 0 ) list.Add(builder());
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type your entity appropriately as a `List<Officer>` (or an appropriately more abstract type (such as `IList`)) and use as normal:

```
entity = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType) as IList;
```

But no need to check whether to insert or not, just insert:

```
entity.Insert(0, officer);
```

I'm assuming (based on the fact that you already know how to create instances using reflection) you're not having trouble creating the instance of type `Officer`.

Comment: The guy does not have the type at compile time.

Comment: Well in that case, they could use a more abstract type for the `as` clause, or direct cast - but in principle, it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Edit after re-reading over your question: This doesn't directly answer your question but is rather a suggestion of a different implementation.

You can easily get by without using reflection:

```
public class TestContainer<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list;

    public TestContainer()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        _list.Add(default(T));
    }

}
```

Then calling e.g.:

```
var t = new TestContainer<YourClass>();
t.Add();
t.Add();
t.Add();
```

you will have a list of 3 instances of YourClass by their default value

Comment: Appreciate it - the question is definitely over simplified, didn't want to get into the reason I'm using reflection, but thanks for the comment!